# Receiving post from C# into PHP

Tags: c#, php, post, get

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I have a program set up (it works and even posts to a demo page that I don't have the code to and returns the correct values back, will post the code shortly) and with the code I am using, I can't find any information on how to read the post from PHP and return the variables back to c#(for the testing phase).  My eventual goal is to gather the information form the post and send it over to the rest of the pages on the same site as the getpost.php page.  If somebody could help me with this I'd be much appreciative.

```
class WebPostRequest
{
    WebRequest theRequest;
    HttpWebResponse theResponse;
    ArrayList theQueryData;

    public WebPostRequest(string url)
    {
        theRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        theRequest.Method = "POST";
        theQueryData = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        theQueryData.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", key, System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)));
    }

    public string GetResponse()
    {
        // Set the encoding type
        theRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Build a string containing all the parameters
        string Parameters = String.Join("&", (String[])theQueryData.ToArray(typeof(string)));
        theRequest.ContentLength = Parameters.Length;

        // We write the parameters into the request
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(theRequest.GetRequestStream());
        sw.Write(Parameters);
        sw.Close();

        // Execute the query
        theResponse = (HttpWebResponse)theRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theResponse.GetResponseStream());
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

}
```

Like I said, on the test page, everything is working fine, the posts are getting received into the test page and transmitted back to my program.

*****UPDATE:::

**Ok, I got the php on my site to gather the POST information from the C# Application.  Now I need to forward that information over to and redirect the user to my other webpage so that they may finish their session and accomplish the reason for them to be at my site.**

Comment: I find the description of what you want to do confusing. You seem to be using `post` in two contexts: http POST data and the everyday usage of posting on the internet. The c# code you show looks like a client-side application. Do you want to know how to make a server hosted php page which accepts http POST data? Please also explain why you want to accept and echo back the same data.

Comment: yes this application i am developing is to help diagnose computer problems.  It gathers simple information from the client and reports it back to server, reports back that it received the information, then redirects to a continue page to further diagnose the rest via php server side.  all done in sessions to destroy all information upon user exiting the site.

Comment: I not know what's your need.in my look,this code works fine. How you are debuging the data receveid of C# in your PHP?

Comment: actually i like i just figured it out.  what i'm doing is from the application, i am sending the information to the php getpost page then the getpost page is writing it to a mysql database and the user then continues with the webpage that they visited to get the diagnostic application.  therefore not redirecting just continueing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP and the post data from others sources sometimes behave in strange ways.
To locate yout problem you can do soemthing like this:

```
$post_from_c = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
```

file_get_contents('php://input') it means that you get the raw data rather than the processed data by apache.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  What I did was collected the post in a PHP and sent it over to a temporary database and call the information from the page the client was already on using the IP and a client password to access (as to eliminate multiple computers on the same IP address) then I created a cron job to erase all data after a certain time, in my case I set it to 3 hours since nobody should be on the site for that time anyway.